# Arduino RFID Mifare Classic dump info

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, rfid

I have my Arduino uno setup with RC522 reader. I am able to dump the data that is held on my test card supplied with the reader but I wish to read the data blocks held within another card I have. The reader shows this as a Mifare classic but Does not dump the blocks.
This is with [miguelbalboa library](https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid)

```
Card UID: EE 67 29 8D
Card SAK: 08
PICC type: MIFARE 1KB
Sector Block   0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9 10 11  12 13 14 15  AccessBits
  15     63  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
  14     59  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
  13     55  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
  12     51  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
  11     47  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
  10     43  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   9     39  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   8     35  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   7     31  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   6     27  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   5     23  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   4     19  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   3     15  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   2     11  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   1      7  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
   0      3  PCD_Authenticate() failed: Timeout in communication.
```

I have also tried using these examples https://github.com/BoolLi/RC522_RFID_NFC_Utilities

But they fail to compile for me. All I want to do is dump the data blocks from a university card I have for a project, I don't need to be able to write to the card yet.

Comment: Failed authentication probably means you're using incorrect secret keys and there's a good chance that you've locked yourself out permanently. Your test card is a blank card from the manufacturer, with the default access conditions still in place. Where's the second card from?

Comment: second card is a uni card I have, it's only use is to allow entry to certain areas ie library and stuff, I have permission to be messing around with it for comp sci project. The card still works after trying this, how would I go about reading with secret keys and such? or even something I could read that covers this.

Comment: My bad. Since authentication failed and you never got to actually accessing the data, I doubt you hurt anything. There's an example in your library (rfid_default_keys) that brute-forces authentication with a bunch of known keys. If those dont work, trying out all 2^48 possibilities is not an option; would take millenia. You can try googling for MIFARE hacks.

Comment: The person who issues the card would know what the SO-PIN is.  When the factory ships the cards they have a Factory SO-PIN which will be published somewhere and then the Uni's card issuance system will(should) change the SO-PIN to something unique to the Uni so it can't be accessed by anyone without this PIN.  I recommend against trying to hack the card, because you only have a certain number of attempts (3 usually) before you irreparably damage the card (I have done many).